# User Controls are released during forward navigation

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm building a windows phone 8.1 application. My home page has some user controls on it. For some reasons user controls are released during forward navigation. So when I navigate back to my home page, user controls are created again. How can I avoid this?

```
public partial sealed MyUserControl : UserControl
{
     myVM MyViewModel;
     public MyUserControl()
     {
          myVM = new MyViewModel(new Composites(new DataAccessRest()));
     }
}
```

I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By default, pages are trashed, once you navigated away (unless you are navigating to the same page your are already on). This is a point where the 8.1 RT app model differs from Silverlight.

The Frame handles caching for you using the **NavigationCacheMode** property of the page. Setting it to Enabled or Required, the Frame will cache the page and reuse it when you navigate to it.

As caching uses a lot of memory, handle cache with care to keep your app from getting closed once in background.

Also: The frames default Cache size is 1. Set it to an appropriate number for you app. Pages with NavigationCacheMode *required* do not count towards the cache size and are always cached.